# update table using condition

Tags: mariadb

I have City and Cars tables and I have this query:

```
UPDATE City
           Set status='good', 
           marke1=(Select marke2 From Cars 
                   where car_id=123 
                     and city_id is null 
                     and country is null )
           Where person_id=789
```

Problem is when country or city_id is not null I am still getting status='good' 
           so I want to use the same (city_id is null and country is null) conditions for status but I'm not good enough in conditional statement. Any help please.

Comment: try using select statement to view the script values first then update table City. And this query will update all the rows in City table status to good.

Comment: person_id is in city table, so thw query will update just one row when person_id = 789

Comment: what is your exact requirement?? would u clear it more?

Comment: i want that the query do nothing when The condition is not met

Comment: because if the condition is met or not the status is becomming good

Comment: so you dont want to change status value to good when that condition is not met yup?

Comment: Give us the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table\G` for both Cars and City! Edit your question to include this data and then post a comment here - with @Vérace in the text! You could also help by including sample data in the form of DML (`INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(....);`)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join tables like that: (not an actual query)

```
UPDATE City AS w
  JOIN Cars AS z ON z.id = w.car_id -- some real condition needed
   SET w.status='good'
 WHERE z.car_id=123 
   AND w.city_id IS NULL 
   AND w.country IS NULL
   AND w.person_id=789
;
```

Show your tables for more specific code.